# Soundmanager 2 does not play mp4 files - when using PHP script for output

Tags: php, javascript, soundmanager2

Here is a weird one,

Soundmanager simply wont play MP4 when using PHP output.

```
soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'sm2-1001',

    url: 'http://mysite.tld/1333092566.mp3', // WORKS
//  url: [{type: 'audio/mp3', url: 'http://mysite.tld/outputmp3.php}], // WORKS
//  url: 'http://mysite.tld/1333092566.mp4', // WORKS
//  url: [{type: 'audio/mp4', url: 'http://mysite.tld/outputmp4.php}], // DOES NOT WORK

    autoLoad: false,
    autoPlay: true,
});
```

URLs are correct, going to http://mysite.tld/outputmp4.php from the browser - opens and plays just fine.

Using smartReadFile.php
https://jplayer.googlegroups.com/attach/f308294ddea52f6c/smartReadFile.php?view=1&part=4

Using latest version of SM2

Debug information from SM2:

```
soundManager.createSound(): sm2-1001 (http://mysite.tld/outputmp4.php)
soundmanager2.js (line 1110)
SMSound() merged options: { id: sm2-1001, url: http://mysite.tld/outputmp4.php, autoLoad: false, autoPlay: true, loops: 1, multiShot: true, multiShotEvents: false, pan: 0, stream: true, usePolicyFile: false, volume: 100, usePeakData: false, useWaveformData: false, useEQData: false, bufferTime: 3 }
soundmanager2.js (line 1112)
SMSound.play(): "sm2-1001" is loading - attempting to play..
soundmanager2.js (line 1110)
SMSound.play(): "sm2-1001" is starting to play
soundmanager2.js (line 1112)
SMSound._onload(): "sm2-1001" loaded.
soundmanager2.js (line 1110)
(Flash): correcting sound sm2-1001 end position (0) to length: 4602
```

Any ideas? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The most likely answer here is that `http://mysite.tld/outputmp4.php` is not generating a valid MP4 file. Put `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 0);` at the top of the PHP script, and check for leading/trailing whitespace outside the `<?php ?>` tags. If your script is stored as UTF-8, make sure it does not have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and if possible convert it to ISO-8859-1. Try downloading and saving the file, and opening it in an editor to make sure that it is a valid MP4 file.

Comment: I thought so too, but how come when I hit http://mysite.tld/outputmp4.php using Firefox/Chrome/IE - it launches the file and plays it just fine? File is valid MP4, otherwise how can you explain when it plays fine when using direct link to it _url: 'http://mysite.tld/1333092566.mp4'_

Comment: Is there any way you can post the actual URL of the script so we can see the output and how the server is handling it? It may be that something about the way SM2 requests the file cause PHP to generate an error message that you don't get from a browser. Disabling error reporting as above would fix this, for double safety disable it in php.ini in case the error is one of those pesky `in /path/file at line 0` errors generated during init. I would also get [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) out to have a look at the raw network data.

Comment: Looking at Apache logs now, no errors posted. SM2 debug shows that it got a file (otherwise will show network error) and started playing it. Firebug (network) shows it got a file (200 OK) and the size is correct. It's very simple to re-create my issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas then, sorry!

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Nope. Tested in FF/Chrome/Opera/Safari/IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing this option to TRUE solved the case.

```
 'isMovieStar': null,      // "MovieStar" MPEG4 audio mode. Null (default) = auto detect MP4, AAC etc. based on URL. true = force on, ignore URL
```

Also this option must be applied since isMovieStar is supported starting from Flash9.

```
soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

`audio/mp4` is not a correct mimetype because mp4 is (designed for) video. Try using `video/mp4`, or just `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: SM2 API declares this as correct format. http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#api soundManager.audioFormats = {}

Comment: It reads and outputs an actual mp4 file (see smartReadFile.php). If jPlayer can play it just fine, as well as browser gets it and launches VLC to play it - I guess Yes - it does its job well. =)